# ¿error en función?

Tags: c++, c

tengo la siguiente función en una biblioteca llamada datas.h que se encarga de segmentar una variables char en tres variables que son numero 1 = 15 numero 2 = 46777215 y country = - pero me da otros valores erróneos y no se cual es el error cuando todo compila correctamente,esta es la cadena que tengo que segmentar `char linea[] = "15,46777215,-,-";`

[image: error logico]

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void Get_values(char linea[],int valor1,int valor2,char country[]){
 
 char numero[100];
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;

    while(linea[i] != ','){

    numero[j++] = linea[i++];
           
   }

  numero[j] = '\0';
  valor1 = atoi(numero); 
  j = 0;
  i++;

  while(linea[i] != ','){

    numero[j++] = linea[i++];
           
   }
  numero[j] = '\0';
  valor2 = atoi(numero); 
  j = 0;
  i++;
  while(linea[i] != ','){
    country[j++] = linea[i++];   
   }    
 }
```

y mi funcion principal

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "datas.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    
  
  int32_t numero1 = 0;
  int32_t numero2 = 0;
  char country[10];
  
  char linea[] = "15,46777215,-,-";
  Get_values(linea,numero1,numero2,country);
  cout<<"numero1:"<<numero1<<endl;
  cout<<"numero2:"<<numero2<<endl;
  cout<<"country:"<<country<<endl;

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que marca?

Comment: @FernandoCarraro me da en el primer valor 0 y en el segundo 0 pero esta leyendo bien el country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te serviría el paso por referencia. Modificar el código de la función del archivo **datas.h**

```
void Get_values(char linea[],int &valor1,int &valor2,char country[]){ 
 char numero[100];
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;
    while(linea[i] != ','){
    numero[j++] = linea[i++];
   }
  numero[j] = '\0';
  valor1 = atoi(numero); 
  j = 0;
  i++;
  while(linea[i] != ','){
    numero[j++] = linea[i++];
   }
  numero[j] = '\0';
  valor2 = atoi(numero); 
  j = 0;
  i++;
  while(linea[i] != ','){
    country[j++] = linea[i++];   
   }    
 }
```

Donde se editó la función `void Get_values(char linea[],int &valor1,int &valor2,char country[])` para obtener los valores de las variables.

Y ya podrías obtener los datos en tu programa principal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "datas.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){  
  int32_t numero1 = 0;
  int32_t numero2 = 0;
  char country[10];
  
  char linea[] = "15,46777215,-,-";
  Get_values(linea,numero1,numero2,country);
  cout<<"numero1:"<<numero1<<endl;
  cout<<"numero2:"<<numero2<<endl;
  cout<<"country:"<<country<<endl;
  return 0;
 }
```

**Salida:**

```
numero1:15
numero2:46777215
country:-
```

Espero te sirva de algo.

Comment: gracias no sabia que se podía hacer eso,sabes porque tengo que usarlo ?

Comment: Es el paso por referencia, si no se usa no se puede acceder a un valor dentro de otra variable o función.